# Azure maps - strange title text showing

Tags: azure-maps

When I hover over my Azure map, I am getting this title text showing up.

[image]

I don't have "Interactive Map" anywhere in my code.  Where is this coming from and how do I get rid of it?

**UPDATE**

@Sloan Haywoods answer below works but must be done after the map has loaded...

```
map.events.add('load', function () {
    map.getCanvas().title = '';
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is part of our new accessibility features, which sets the title property of the map's canvas element. The title can be modified or removed using:

```
map.getCanvas().title = "<new title or empty string to remove>"
```